# Error with permission policy header: unrecognized feature: ch-ua-form-factor and Access to XMLHttprequest

Tags: cors, xmlhttprequest, protocols, policy

```
     <iframe width="1000" height="550"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/key" allow="autoplay; fullscreen;">
    </iframe>
```

i got this error in my vite.js application where i try to play youtube video in i frame tag using tmdb api

without using i frame tag error removes .

[image][image]